# Get a sum from one table and update a column in another using SQL server

Tags: sql-server

```
table 1 = customer | primary-key = customer.sid
table 2 = orders   | foreign-key = orders.customer_sid
```

I would like to `sum orders.sale_amount where customer.sid = orders.customer_sid and update customer.sales_total`.

I am new to SQl and here was my original statement (which doesn't work)

```
 UPDATE customer
 inner JOIN orders ON (customer.sid = orders.customer_Sid)
 SET customer.sales_total = SUM(orders.sale_amount)
 GROUP BY customer.sid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update customer
Set Total=Od.Tot
From customer C 
    cross apply (Select SUM (O.sale_amount) Tot 
                From Orders O Where O.customer_Sid=C.sid) Od
```

Comment: Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501
> Update customer
Set Total=Od.Tot
From customer C 
    cross apply (Select SUM (O.sale_amount) Tot 
                From Orders O Where O.customer_Sid=C.sid) Od
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = From ]

Comment: @RobertStraight: Are you using this as dynamic query somewhere ?